# What does this logical symbol "A" in topological chapter of Mathematical Analysis 2 (Zorich) mean?

Tags: general-topology

[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNWXE.png) [image: Pic 1]

In Definition 1 b), there is a symbol 'A', but I can't understand its meaning.
I get to know the whole sentence b) by other book (Munkres topology, in the picture below).

[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6W8b.png) [image: Pic 2]

Also I know b) is a first-order logical sentence, but the symbol 'A' does not have a quantifier. Does it occur free in this sentence? Or it is just a constant symbol (and if so, what does it mean?).

Comment: I think you're making a mistake trying to read it as a properly formed sentence of first order logic. It's merely convenient shorthand for "Suppose $A$ is a set, and that for each $\alpha\in A$ we have a set $\tau_\alpha$. If all the $\tau_\alpha$ are members of  $\tau$ so is their union."

Comment: I have edited the post so that pictures are displayed (and the readers do not have to click the link to display the relevant potions). At eh same time, I have corrected some typos. (Of course, if it now seems that the picture take up too space and that the original version is better, you should feel free to edit the post again to get the version with links instead of pictures.)

Comment: Here, $A$ is any index set for a family of open sets. The author should introduce it properly. Without mentioning any index set, b) says: $\tau$ is closed under arbitrary unions, or equivalently, the union of any subset of $\tau$ is a member of $\tau$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don’t worry. It’s just any index set. If you want to be formal about it (don’t be, though) it’s a sort of free parameter in this sentence. We just have an open set $\tau_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$ in the index set $A$. It states exactly the same closedness under unions as pic 2 does.

I could also have said

$$\forall \tau’ \subseteq \tau: \bigcup \tau’ \in \tau$$